# Airflow - How do I ignore succeeded tasks in a backfill?

Tags: airflow

I have added new tasks to my DAG and it needs to backfill them. At the moment, when I run `airflow backfill` it runs all the tasks(new ones and the old ones) and I would like to ignore the old tasks which have already succeeded.

Is there any way to skip the tasks with success state in a backfill?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Airflow version 1.8.1, successful tasks should not be scheduled by a backfill, see [AIRFLOW-1124](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1124).

Note that you can also specify which tasks you want to run in a backfill:

```
-t TASK_REGEX, --task_regex TASK_REGEX
                    The regex to filter specific task_ids to backfill
                    (optional)
```

The ignore dependencies flag may also help you in case your new tasks depend on any old ones that may not have succeeded.

```
-i, --ignore_dependencies
                    Skip upstream tasks, run only the tasks matching the
                    regexp. Only works in conjunction with task_regex
```

Comment: If you want to backfill all tasks from v 1.8.1+ you need to do an airflow clear before. i.e. `airflow clear -s 2018-06-11 -e 2018-06-11 my_dag` and then `airflow backfill -s 2018-06-11 -e 2018-06-11 my_dag`. Note that clear command will delete the metadata of the task instances, as if the dag has never run in that day.